# Unable to assign random node attributes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I want to generate 10 random graphs with different node attributes but with the same underlying configuration (4 nodes and the same edge arrangements). Randomness is associated with the values of the node attributes only.

Each node has two attributes: expertise_level and innovation_level. The objective is to have 10 graphs, each with a random set of values (High/Medium/Low) for these two attributes.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

masterG = [] #to store generated graphs in a list
G = nx.path_graph(4) #creating a specific 4-node graph configuration

def randompicking(levels = ["High", "Medium", "Low"]):
    abc = np.random.choice(levels, len(list(G)), replace = True, p=[0.33, 0.33, 0.34])
    return abc.tolist()

def initializeG():
    expertise_level  = dict(list(enumerate(randompicking())))
    innovation_level = dict(list(enumerate(randompicking())))
    
    nx.set_node_attributes(G, expertise_level,  'expertise_level')
    nx.set_node_attributes(G, innovation_level, 'innovation_level')

for i in range(10):
    initializeG()
    masterG.append(G)

masterG
```

The problem: When I am running the code manually for generating each graph by unpacking the code inside intializeG() and moving the code outside of this function (i.e., not creating this function but using the inside code in the global environment), the node attributes generated are random (unique) in each graph as desired. However, when I am running the code using the function initializeG() as above, the node attributes generated for each node in each graph (stored in masterG) are exactly the same.

Can anyone explain where the code is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a unique graph here as you're reusing your graph. See how the ID is the same:

```
[<networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500c7e9d0>,
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500c7e9d0>,
...
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500c7e9d0>,
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500c7e9d0>]
```

You need to create a **new** graph each time you call `initializeG`:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

masterG = [] #to store generated graphs in a list

def randompicking(levels = ["High", "Medium", "Low"]):
    abc = np.random.choice(levels, len(list(G)), replace = True, p=[0.33, 0.33, 0.34])
    return abc.tolist()

def initializeG():
    G = nx.path_graph(4) #creating a specific 4-node graph configuration
    expertise_level  = dict(list(enumerate(randompicking())))
    innovation_level = dict(list(enumerate(randompicking())))
    
    nx.set_node_attributes(G, expertise_level,  'expertise_level')
    nx.set_node_attributes(G, innovation_level, 'innovation_level')
    return G

for i in range(10):
    G = initializeG()
    masterG.append(G)
```

output (now IDs are different, each graph is a different object):

```
[<networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500ab4b80>,
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500ab47c0>,
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500ab4970>,
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500c45160>,
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500c452b0>,
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500c45040>,
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f35009536d0>,
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500c45220>,
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500c45430>,
 <networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x7f3500c45400>]
```

Comment: Thanks, Mozway. This worked. I did try G_temp = G and return G_temp inside initializeG(). Why did that fail? Seems like a similar approach to yours. I apologize if I am missing something terribly simple here.

Comment: `G_temp = G` doesn't create a copy but a new name pointing to the **same** object ;)

Comment: You would need to use `G_temp = G.copy()`

Comment: Noted, thanks Mozway. Just one last clarification: Even if we are not creating a copy, the  nx.set_node_attributes() function should modify the node attributes for G in each run, since it is using randompicking(). I know it does not modify as you said, but I am curious about the reason for it.

Comment: It **does** modify but as you have a **single** object, this is modifying **all** the occurrences ;)

Comment: It is the same pitfall as often seen with lists, try: `l = [[0]]*5 ; l[0][0] = 1 ; l` and see how all are modified, because there is actually a **single** object ;)

Comment: I see. I still don't fully get the logic, but that is a function of the gap in my knowledge. I will try to figure this out in-depth.